# passing array between two servers

Tags: php

In server (a) i have a script that do some stuff,when the task completed it return an array like this :

```
Array ( [1372888] => 3 - 0 [1340712] => 0 - 0 );
```

I need to pass this array to server (b).It is possible to do this ?.

Comment: This needs more info. What kinds of servers? Running what?

Comment: `json_encode()` --> `json_decode()`

Comment: serialize() --> unserialize()

Comment: @Pranav sure, go ahead! This page has more: http://fsymbols.com/keyboard/ (not all work though, you need text characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use json to pass the data:

Server A:

```
$array = array("1372888" => "3 - 0", "1340712" => "0 - 0")
$passArray = json_encode($array) ;
/// Send
```

Server B:

```
// Receive data:
$array = json_decode($array,true);
```